# how to call async function assinged to object in node.js

Tags: node.js

In value of below AWS Lambda code the call of options.ensurePrivateKeyForApi should wait for a return value but looks like it is not. Turns out the code is not waiting but using await in front gives error.
Logic is as follows: If the global variable apiKey is not holding a value it should go to AWS SecretsManager and pick up the secret and move it to the global variable (in order to avoid frequent calls to SecretsManager).
For unit testing purposes I moved the async function to the options object that will be replaced for unit testing.

How can I make it wait?

```
var apiPrivateKey;

function setPrivateKey(secretString) {
  apiPrivateKey = secretString;
}

async function ensurePrivateKeyForApi() {
  if (!(typeof apiPrivateKey === "string" || apiPrivateKey instanceof String) {
    let secret = await secretsManager.getSecretValue({
      SecretId: process.env.JWT_SECRET_NAME
    }).promise();
    setPrivateKey(secret.SecretString);
  }
}
var options = {
  ensurePrivateKeyForApi
};

function handler(event, context, callback) {
  //...
  
  options.ensurePrivateKeyForApi(); // that line should wait but compiler complains about await
  console.log("secret " + apiPrivateKey); // secret is always undefined
}

module.exports = {
  handler,
  options,
  setPrivateKey
};
```

Comment: was there any issue in adding `async` to `handler function` ?

Comment: no, you can use either one, right? async or callback. so I went for callback as this what the example used

Comment: oh, but I just realize where that is going...no async, no await..., right?

Comment: That is correct, no async, no await.